# Delete an object from a list

Tags: c, generic-list

My list item:

```
typdef struct sNode
{
   struct sNode* next;
   myData data;
} tNode;
```

I wish to implement the following API:

```
bool removeNode(tNode* node)
{
... // need to fix list and free node
}
```

The problem is that I do not have the previous element to modify.
Is there some kind of magic to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You would have to traverse from the beginning of the list to find the previous node, which is pretty inefficient.  This is the problem with singly-linked lists. If you need this to be fast, use a doubly-linked list (each node has a *next* and a *previous* pointer).

Comment: Thanks. But in this case, I can also implement circular link list. In this case, I do not need to chang my API or structure. Then I can seach my node. I was hoping there will be some kind of magic

Answer (score 1):

You are using a single linked list, if you want to remove a node from the list, you should traverse the list from head. So, you need to change your API to something like this:

```
bool removeNode(tNode * head, tNode* node);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes (almost) -- you could copy the contents of `node->next` into `node` and then delete `node->next` instead.

In pseudocode:

```
sNode* next = node->next; // see below for an important special case
node->data = next->data;
node->next = next->next;
free(next);
```

The reason I say "almost" is that this doesn't work if `node` has no successor. In this case you have to traverse the list from the beginning.

Additionally, you have to consider the extra cost of copying `data`.

If you often delete nodes by pointer, you should think about whether a singly-linked list is the right data structure. For example, a doubly-linked list does not have this problem (but does have the additional overhead of one extra pointer per node).

Comment: @BlackBear: Yes. :) It's pseudo-code because we don't quite know what `myData` is.

Comment: @aix: I wonder if it will still work for c++, in case data is an abstract object. In this case, in one node it can be object from Type A, and in the next node from Type B. In this case you cannot copy B into A (not in an easy way). But thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @user752716: The question is tagged as C :) You're right about C++ though: if `data` is copied by value (as opposed to by pointer), slicing could be a problem.